# Reverting git merge and consecutive commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-reset

I had a troublesome time trying to merge a branch with the master, as the merge tried to delete files and changes that were on the master that I needed to keep. I ended up committing a partial broken merge to the master and I made quite a few commits after that trying to resolve the issue.

Now I want to undo all of this by resetting the master to its original state. I'm the only one who made changes to the master so other users shouldn't be an issue. Will doing a hard reset to a previous commit be enough? Or is there some other step I need to take to make sure the reset doesn't cause issues in future merges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard reset will suffice, since it will reset all files to their state in the specified commit.

For example, `git reset --hard HEAD~3` will reset all files to the third-last commit, no matter what happened to them in the last three commits. Your files will be in a state as if these commits never happened.

Instead of using the `HEAD~X` notation, you can of course just use the SHA id of the commit you want to reset to.

EDIT: Obligatory words of warning: If anyone pulled and is working on your changes, things will go haywire if they try to merge their work into the master you resetted. Also, `reset --hard` deletes all uncommited changes without any chance to get them back.